# Child level <ul> height issue

Tags: html, css

I know it'll be sillest Question ever!!, but having a Query regarding the height of sub level `<ul>`, i am not getting the full height of child  tag.

```
<div class="nav megaMenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                    <ul class="sub-nav" >
                        <li class="sub-nav-col" ><a href="#">About us A</a>
                            <ul class="sub-inner">
                                <li><a href="#">About us A 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About us A 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">About us A 3</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Links A</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Links C 1</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Links B</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Links B 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Links B 2</a></li>

                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">level-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">level-2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">level-2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
}
.nav ul{
display:table;
margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;

}
.nav > ul > li.level1{
   position:static; 
}
.nav ul li {
 display: table-cell;
 transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
 position: relative;
}
.nav li a {
 transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
 display:block;
}
.nav > ul > li > a {
 background: #f5f5f5;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 padding: 10px;
}
.nav > ul > li:last-child > a {
 border-right: none;
}
 .nav {
 position: relative;
}
.nav.megaMenu > ul > li > ul{
 left: 0;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 z-index:9;
 height:100%;
    background:red;
}
.nav.megaMenu > ul {
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
max-width: 1024px;
}
.nav.megaMenu li.level2 ul li {
width:100%;
}
.nav.megaMenu > ul li:hover ul {
visibility:visible;
}

.nav > ul > li ul {
 visibility:hidden;
 z-index: 9;
 position: absolute;
}
.nav > ul > li.level1 ul li a {
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 color: #fff;
 display: block;
 margin-right: 1px;
 padding: 10px;
}
```

you can get the working demo @ [here](http://jsfiddle.net/imchaitanya9/8pzaLp83/). at here when you hover on menu, you will find the red background coloured `<ul>` which contains sub children too, but the height of `<ul>` is not covering the height of full heirarchy. please help me for this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the absolute parent on child ul since the parent is already in absolute position.

```
.nav > ul > li ul {
 visibility:hidden;
 z-index: 9;
}
```

Demo: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8pzaLp83/1/)